# Win7 won't let me execute the WinZip installer

Tags: security, download, windows-7

I downloaded the WinZip installer, but Win7 won't let me execute it. It says the site it came from is not trusted.

I set the security level for the Internet zone to the lowest level (Medium) but it still won't execute.

I tried to add winzip.com as a trusted site, but it wouldn't let me since it wasn't https.

I added the url to the local Intranet level, but it still wouldn't execute the program.

Why can't I execute an installer for a program as ubiquitous as WinZip?

Answer (score 0):

Hidden Behind the popup that said I had to change security levels, was another popup that said I needed Administrator privileges.

I only found it when I started to clear the screen.

So I rebooted and logged on as administrator and executed the program.